# How to calculate this surface integral

Tags: fourier-transform, surface-integrals

In a calculation about a Fourier transform, I stumbled in the following surface integral. Let $\mathcal{S}_r$ be the sphere of radius $r>0$ centered in $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$ be the $n-1$ dimensional Hausdorff measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, I've no idea how to explicitly calculate: $$\int_{S_r}e^{-ix\cdot \xi}d\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\xi).$$
It is even possible to give an explicit formula? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fourier transform of the unit sphere is expressed in terms of a Bessel function: see [Fourier transform of the unit sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/q/149692) on MathOverflow. It is also briefly discussed on this site, in the question [About the Fourier transform of the surface measure of the unit sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/993917).